# Export frames to video on mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, video, mov

I managed capturing video frames from a video card using Black Magic SDK.
I can store the video frames.

What I dont know how is it possible to export (render) a video file from captured frames.
I would like to create a .mov video from them and store it on HDD.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FrameByFrame source code](https://github.com/brend/FrameByFrame), especially the [FBQuickTimeExporter](https://github.com/brend/FrameByFrame/blob/master/Classes/FBQuickTimeExporter.m) class. This code generates a movie from individual `NSImage` objects at the desired frame rate (wrapped in a `FBReel` object, but you can ignore that).